# Как правильно написать имя при изменении существующего представления?

Tags: c#, mono, android, monodroid

Есть класс который наследует TextView

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using  Android.Graphics;

namespace HelloWorld
{
class TodoListItemView:TextView
{
    private Paint marginPaint;
    private Paint linePaint;
    private int paperColor;
    private float margin;

    public TodoListItemView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int ds): base (context, attrs, ds)
    {
        init();
    }

    public TodoListItemView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        Resources myResources = Resources;
        marginPaint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
        marginPaint.Color = myResources.GetColor(Resource.Color.notepad_margin);
        linePaint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
        linePaint.Color = myResources.GetColor(Resource.Color.notepad_lines);
        paperColor = myResources.GetColor(Resource.Color.notepad_paper);
        margin = myResources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.notepad_margin);

    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {

        canvas.DrawLine(0, 0, Height, 0, linePaint);
        canvas.DrawLine(0, Height, Width, Height, linePaint);
        // Нарисуйте кромку
        canvas.DrawLine(margin, 0, margin, Height, marginPaint);
        // Переместите текст в сторону от кромки
        canvas.Save();
        canvas.Translate(margin, 0);
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        canvas.Restore();
    }

}
```

}

и есть разметка todolist_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TodoListItemView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textColor="@color/notepad_text"
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
/>
```

у меня указано TodoListItemView, но с таким именем оно не работает, возникает ошибка при открытии разметки.
Есть пример на Java, ну так как там packages, все ясно

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.paad.todolist.TodoListItemView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textColor="@color/notepad_text"
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
/>
```

Какое имя указать мне?

Comment: Запустился в андроид эмуляторе после того как поставил правильный Namespace контролу: - 

    <MyNameSpace.TestTextView

Answer (score 1):

В лайоуте отобразился сразу.
Запустился в андроид эмуляторе после того как поставил правильный Namespace контролу: -

```
<MyNameSpace.TestTextView
```

Исходники:

```
class TestTextView:TextView
{

    [Register (".ctor", "(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet; I) V", "")]
    public TestTextView(Context context,  IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base (context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
         Text = "TEST TEST TEST";
    }
}
// ***************************************************  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff96aa85">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="52.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp" />
    <MyNameSpace.TestTextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/TestText1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Импорты:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;

using Android.Text;
using Android.Text.Method;
using Android.Text.Style;
using Android.Text.Util;
using Android.Util;

using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Java.Interop;
using Java.Lang;

Comment: так же не запускается

Comment: Где exception?

Comment: unfortunately has stopped

Comment: Если скопировать в todolist_item.xml, все работает

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@android:id/text1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:paddingLeft="6dip" 
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"/>

Comment: Вы из МоnoDevelop запускаете? запустите в дебаг режиме.

Comment: Нет, Visual Studio

Comment: Тогда не знаю как поступить.